I have a string that is defined, then is changed in a method called after it's defined, the value is still that which it is defined as. Why? c#
I am building a console app in C#, I have a few variables that are defined at the start of the program, and then immediately after I call a method. The method references those variables, because it changes some of them. A little after I call the method that utilizes those variables, and it does so with the original definitions, and not the ones defined in the prior method.
These are the code snippets relevant to the question:
string foregroundColor = "White";
string backgroundColor = "Black";
testMap1(ref map, foregroundColor, backgroundColor);

static void testMap1(ref string[,] map, string foregroundColor, string backgroundColor)
{
    resetMap(ref map, foregroundColor, backgroundColor);
    foregroundColor = "Red";
    backgroundColor = "Black";

static void resetMap(ref string[,] map, string foregroundColor, string backgroundColor)
{
    foregroundColor = "White";
    backgroundColor = "Black";

static void displayPosition2(ref string[,] map, int[] place, string foregroundColor, string backgroundColor)
{
    if (foregroundColor == "Red")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "Green")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "Yellow")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "Magenta")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "DarkGreen")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "Black")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "Blue")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "Cyan")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "DarkBlue")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "DarkCyan")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "DarkGrey")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "DarkMagenta")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "DarkRed")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "DarkYellow")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
    }
    else if (foregroundColor == "Gray")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }

After this it should output text in red, but it outputs in white, after a few tests, the problem lies in the first definition being used in the displayposition2 method.
I would like to know why this isn't working as intended, everyone I have talked to in real life has said that it should work.

Are they in a static class?

Also, avoid using the same name for local variables and parameters.

foregroundColor and backgroundColor are not ref, so you only change their values locally.

fyi -- there's no good reason to use ref for the map array based on the code we can see. Arrays are already by passed by reference.

Oh, and we're missing a lot of closing braces in there for the methods. The question would be a lot clearer if you would add those back in.

That's just because I only put the relevant parts of the code, these are just excerpts of a larger program.

We can explain the issue looking at just this much of the code:
string foregroundColor = "White";
testMap1(ref map, foregroundColor);

static void testMap1(ref string[,] map, string foregroundColor)
{
    foregroundColor = "Red";
}

Let's examine what happens with the initial foregroundColor string variable after we pass it to the method.
First, string is a reference type, even though it has special handling in the compiler to sometimes get value semantics. This means the initial foregroundColor variable does not hold the text "White" directly, but rather holds a reference to a string object somewhere else in memory with "White" as the value. When  we call the method, we only pass the reference. So far this seems to be in line with expectations, and would be true even if the ref keyword never appeared in the code.
Next, the method has its own string parameter also named foregroundColor. This is a different variable than the foregroundColor defined previously1. When we call the method it is given a reference to the same string object as the variable defined before calling the method. Again, this seems to be in line with expectations.
This is where things sometimes start to veer from expectations. This reference passed to the method is a copy of the reference from the other variable. It refers to the same location, but it's still a different reference. This means the variables are not linked. And just in case, the ref used before the map argument only applies to that one argument2, so it's not in play here.
Now we do an assignment for the foregroundColor variable local to the method:
foregroundColor = "Red";

This assignment does not modify the string object in memory. It creates a new string object, and gives a reference for that object to the foregroundColor variable... but only the variable local to the method. The original foregroundColor defined outside the method is unchanged.
Now you could fix this by adding a ref keyword to the method parameter definition... but don't do that. You're much better off defining a class or similar with properties for your foregroundColor and other items. Then have an instance of that class you can pass around. That way, you are changing a property of the same object, and the results are visible in the places you expect. Even better practice still is creating a new instance of the settings object with the correct values, but explaining why would be mean going deep into the weeds on functional programming theory.
Finally, the other issue here is, from what we can see, _displayPosition2() is never called. This means we don't know how it fits with other code that might be resetting things, or which version of the variable is used.

1)  Name collisions like this are poor-practice... something to avoid. You should give one of them a different name.
2) Based on the code we can see, the ref keyword is not useful or helpful here for the map parameter, and should be removed.

"In C#, strings are immutable, citing this MS article "String objects are immutable: they can't be changed after they're created. All of the String methods and C# operators that appear to modify a string actually return the results in a new string object."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#immutability-of-strings

This has nothing to do with the question and is in fact misleading. The question has to do with how an Lvalue is passed around

Hard disagree. See Joel's response.

He was not calling methods or using operators. He was expecting the assignment of a new string to the parameter to propagate to the variable passed as an argument to the method. Therefore, it makes no difference whether string is immutable or not in this case because assignment cannot be overloaded and by default, C# passes everything by value. If he had defined the parameter as ref string and updated the callsite to add ref to the argument, the code would have worked as he expected. Also, his answer isn't great.
